# Direct link to local kml file

Tags: apache, google-maps, kml

I run an apache webserver on ubuntu 16.04
I am creating many kml files on my server and I want the user to click a link that will automatically open the kml on google maps (and not download it)

e.g. click to open map doesn't open the file, it only downloads it.

If I host the file on google drive and get the shareable link to it, and I use this link everything works great (I can use it as a simple href in a HTML page).
Unfortunately, doing it through google drive is not a feasible option for me (too many files, high update rate).

Is there any other way I can do it with local file?

Comment: Try looking at using [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) or [Cesium](https://cesiumjs.org/) for the maps -- both support KML files served locally.

Comment: thank you for these great options. Before I go and use them, I must ask: are there any non 3rd party solutions that will still use Google maps?